# rake db populate with geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, rails-geocoder

I want to populate my database with 300 users and products, but the process is too fast, and so are the requests to Google API. How can I slow it down ? (1 request every second max).
I tried that in the **config/environments/development.rb** but it didn't worked :

```rb
Geocoder.configure(timeout: 10000)
```

Here is what Geocoder renders :

```rb
Geocoding API not responding fast enough (use Geocoder.configure(:timeout => ...) to set limit).
```

Answer (score 0):

I think setting the timeout config on Geocoder will only let Geocoder wait longer for an external API response, it won't help you populating the db at a slower pace. And I believe that's what you want as external APIs may not be able to answer a huge amount of simultaneous calls from your app.

You may need to try something like this

```
 Product.populate 300 do |product|
   sleep 0.2
   ...
 end
```